# Adding relations in code only

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given that:

- the database model cannot be touched (database provided by a supplier; we would loose support if we were changing the data)
- all relations between entities are missing

typically, we do have a users table with id, name... and a transaction table with id, user_id, amount...
As there is no relation at the DB level, Entity Framework does not relates the objects together and there is no way to use constructs like:

```
transactions.Select(t=> new {t.id, t.user.name, t.amount})
```

Is there a way to manually add the relationship in the Entity Framework (model first) so we can leverage Linq?

Comment: So, if there are no relationships defined, how did your supplier ensure referntial integrity? Triggers?

Comment: I suppose they manually do it at code level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it it possible.

**Model first**

In the edmx designer, right click > Add New > Association. You'll get a dialog to set up the relationship between the two models:

[image]

**Code first**

Something similar to the following model setup should work, even without relationships present on the database:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

public class Transaction
{
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

---

When your models are setup in this way, the following LINQ:

```
transactions.Select(t=> new {t.id, t.user.name, t.amount});
```

Should then be possible, and will be converted nicely into SQL by EF when running.

Comment: How do you achieve that when generating model from database? Is it safe to edit auto-generated model?

Comment: Absolutely my mistake, I read code first!!! :s I'll leave this here for reference.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do this in the edmx designer, right click > Add New > Association.  You'll get a dialog to set up the relationship.

Comment: your answer absolutely helped. Sorry for the VERY long time to get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all the classes generated with the Entity Framework are `partial`. This means you can add to the project a second .cs file where you can add the same class (within the same namespace) and add your own methods to it. There you could add your own `AddRelationsToDataSet()` method, which won't be touched if you make any changes through the designer on your model.

The only drawback is, that you have to manually call this method each and everywhere after the constructor. Or you create a static `Create()` method within your partial class part that calls the constructor and afterwards your method. Then you simply have to check that nobody calls the constructor directly but only through your creator method.